# Use matplollib.pyplot without opening graph window

Tags: matplotlib, graph

This might sound weird but I'd like to know if it is possible.

The reason why I'm asking this is because I work on a sound recognition code and I use the `plt.specgram()` function.

My problem is that when I'm putting a sound sample, I don't want to see the graph because I don't need it. It is more annoying than helping...

I tried using `pylab.specgram()` instead but the graph window keeps on showing.
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using pylab mode. By default, pylab will show the plot ("interactive mode").

You can stop interactive mode by:

```
plt.ioff() 
pylab.ioff()
ioff() # if name space is 'from pylab import *'
```

This should stop showing/updating the plot every time you call some plotting function.

Once you have done drawing, you can do one of those:

```
plt.show()
pylab.show()
show()
```

Also, when you want the interactive mode back on:

```
ion()
```